# How to configure CXF servlet in Springboot 2.1.1 Final?

Tags: apache, soap, cxf

PLease find the error I am facing : 
     In springboot 2.1.1 I am getting below error :

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:  Parameter 1 of constructor in
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
>   required a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath'
>   that could not be found.
>        The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
>     - Bean method 'dispatcherServletRegistration' in 'DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration'
>   not loaded because DispatcherServlet Registration found non dispatcher
>   servlet dispatcherServlet
>
> Action:
>
> Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath'
>   in your configuration.

My configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class CXFConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {

        final ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFCdiServlet(), "/services/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        SpringBus springBus = new SpringBus();
        springBus.getInInterceptors().add(new AppInboundInterceptor());
        springBus.getOutInterceptors().add(new AppOutboundInterceptor());
        return springBus;
    }

}
```

Please confirm how to do the configuration?

`dispatcherServlet()` method doesn't work in `Springboot 2.1.1`

Comment: @Bean
 public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
 final ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean =   new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFCdiServlet(), "/services/*");
  servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
  return servletRegistrationBean;
}

Comment: above method dosent works in Springboot 2.1.1

Comment: @Bean(name=Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {    
     SpringBus springBus = new SpringBus();
        springBus.getInInterceptors().add(new AppInboundInterceptor());
     springBus.getOutInterceptors().add(new AppOutboundInterceptor());
     return springBus;
    }

Comment: above 2 methods are in my @Configuration
public class CXFConfig

Comment: you can edit the question and add the comments...

Comment: Are you using cxf rest or cxf soap, standalone spring boot application with embedded tomcat or deploying it on some app server?

Comment: Hi Karthik , cxf soap with embedded tomcat in Springboot 2.1.1

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by change the method name from dispatcherServlet to disServlet.
Maybe you can try.